# A specific string in an XML with the same name

Tags: c#

There is an xml file that is on the developer's site (steam to be more precise).
I'm trying to read statistics from a certain game. But how to do that?
All subfolders are called message.
If they were called messageid12345 and the other message was message1111, then it would be all simple. But how do you capture information for a particular game with the same name for the subfolder? For example, the game on the subfolder: 5 (appid 50).
More thanks in advance for the help)

```
XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
doc2.Load("http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=123456789&steamid=" + label3.Text + @"&format=xml");
XmlElement root2 = doc1.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList nodes2 = root.SelectNodes("/response/games/message"); // ????? <----
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes2)
{
    string playedtime = node["playtime_forever"].InnerText;
    rust_playtime.Text = playedtime;
}
```

XML looks like this

```html
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<response>
<game_count>170</game_count>
<games>
<message>
<appid>10</appid>
<playtime_forever>11620</playtime_forever>
</message>
<message>
<appid>20</appid>
<playtime_forever>0</playtime_forever>
</message>
<message>
<appid>30</appid>
<playtime_forever>0</playtime_forever>
</message>
<message>
<appid>40</appid>
<playtime_forever>0</playtime_forever>
</message>
<message>
<appid>50</appid>
<playtime_forever>0</playtime_forever>
</message>
<message>
<appid>60</appid>
<playtime_forever>0</playtime_forever>
</message>
<message>
<appid>70</appid>
<playtime_forever>0</playtime_forever>
</message>
<message>
<appid>130</appid>
<playtime_forever>0</playtime_forever>
</message>
<message>
<appid>2500</appid>
<playtime_forever>303</playtime_forever>
</message>
</games>
</response>
```

Comment: You're basically already there. You just need a `string appid =node["appid"]` call and then test if the appid is what you want. There's probably an XPath way to do it too but that might be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: if i call this - nothing happens ;(

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you need set a condition in your loop, to find the one message, where appid equals to the one, you need. Or you can parse this response into object, which contains messages as list of responses. Then work with this list, using LINQ.